# Why indexing with boolean array flatten result?

Tags: python, numpy

Here is an example code:

```
a = np.ones((2,2,1)) > 0
b = np.ones((2,2,3))
c = np.tile(a, [1,1,3])

a.shape
(2, 2, 1)
b.shape
(2, 2, 3)
c.shape
(2, 2, 3)
b[c].shape
(12,)
```

Why `b[c].shape` is `(12,)`? i.e. why result is flatten after indexing?

Comment: What shape would expect `b[c]` to be if some elements of `c` where `false`?

Comment: For example if `c[0][0][1] = False` this leaves `b` with 11 elements. How can that be shaped to a matrix of the original size?

Answer (score 0):

Because indexing with Boolean is used for filtering **values**, so flattening is [by design](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

> #### Boolean array indexing

> If `obj.ndim == x.ndim`, `x[obj]` returns a 1-dimensional array filled with the elements of `x` corresponding to the `True` values of `obj`. The search order will be row-major, C-style. If `obj` has `True` values at entries that are outside of the bounds of `x`, then an index error will be raised. If `obj` is smaller than `x` it is identical to filling it with `False`.

To get rid of **columns**, you have to index with integers to perform slicing. Filters may be converted to slices with e.g. `numpy.any`.